# Can backup unused html files slow a server down?:

Tags: html

A client of mine has a number of old HTML files that aren't being used on his website.
I was wondering if those files can cause the server to slow down?

Example:

He has 10 index.html files, only one is being used, the rest are backups form previous changes.

```
index.html <- only one that's live
index010113.html
index010114.html
index010115.html
```

etc.

Those other files can be pulled up if they are typed out manually.

Comment: No, they won't slow it down.

Comment: As far as the speed at which the server 'serves up' the pages, no.

Answer (score 1):

Not by any appreciable amount, no.  It's still not a good idea to keep old files hanging around.  This is what version control systems are designed to manage.  Use a VCS such as Git to handle things like this.